# Cannot install .ipa OTA created by "Save for Enterprise Deployement" in XCode 6.1.1

Tags: ios, xcode, ota

**Update 10-02-2015:** By using XCode-beta Version 6.2 (6C86e), it works well now.

Since I've updated my XCode (from XCode5) to version 6.1 then 6.1.1, I cannot install the application OTA (In House distribution). I can create archive and then using Organiser to export the archive using "Save for Enterprise Deployement" without any problem. XCode organiser recognize well the Enterprise Account and found the provisioning profile to use.

[image]

[image]

[image]

After exported the .ipa file, I used an old .plist to create OTA install link. From the iPod, when I click to the link, it seems that iPod downloaded the .ipa correctly. Then, it appeared "Installing..." and then I failed with the Message "Unable to Download Application".

[image]

**Actually, I have a workaround for this problem: use xcodebuild command to export manually the .ipa. It works well. But I would like to fix this in XCode.**

```
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath $projectname.xcarchive -exportPath $projectname -exportFormat ipa -exportProvisioningProfile “Provisioning Profile Name”
```

My .plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>items</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>assets</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>software-package</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>__URL___</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>full-size-image</string>
                    <key>needs-shine</key>
                    <false/>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>__FULL_SIZE_IMAGE__</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>display-image</string>
                    <key>needs-shine</key>
                    <false/>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>__DISPLAY_IMAGE__</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>metadata</key>
            <dict>
                <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                <string>__BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER__</string>
                <key>bundle-version</key>
                <string>2.0.7</string>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>software</string>
                <key>title</key>
                <string>__TITLE_</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

And here is the log in Xcode Console during the installation:

```
Dec  4 15:41:29 iPod-de-aabarar itunesstored[91] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installing placeholder for __BUNDLE___
Dec  4 15:41:30 iPod-de-aabarar installd[60] <Notice>: 0x283000 handle_install_for_ls: Install of "/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.itunesstored/AppPlaceholders/-9133206698769979491.app" requested by itunesstored
Dec  4 15:41:30 iPod-de-aabarar installd[60] <Notice>: 0x283000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Installing app __BUNDLE___
Dec  4 15:41:30 iPod-de-aabarar installd[60] <Notice>: 0x283000 install_application: Installing placeholder
Dec  4 15:41:30 iPod-de-aabarar installd[60] <Notice>: 0x283000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Staging: 0.03s; Waiting: 0.00s; Installation: 0.27s; LS Sync: 0.00s; Overall: 0.30s
Dec  4 15:41:30 iPod-de-aabarar iap2d[1207] <Warning>: process com.apple.mobilesafari is now running in the background
Dec  4 15:41:31 iPod-de-aabarar itunesstored[91] <Warning>: LaunchServices: updating placeholder for __BUNDLE___ with icons
Dec  4 15:41:31 iPod-de-aabarar installd[60] <Notice>: 0x283000 handle_install_for_ls: Install of "/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.itunesstored/AppPlaceholders/-9133206698769979491.app" requested by itunesstored
Dec  4 15:41:31 iPod-de-aabarar installd[60] <Notice>: 0x283000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Installing app __BUNDLE___
Dec  4 15:41:31 iPod-de-aabarar installd[60] <Notice>: 0x283000 install_application: Installing placeholder
Dec  4 15:41:31 iPod-de-aabarar installd[60] <Notice>: 0x283000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Staging: 0.01s; Waiting: 0.00s; Installation: 0.09s; LS Sync: 0.00s; Overall: 0.11s
Dec  4 15:41:31 iPod-de-aabarar itunesstored[91] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Creating installProgressForApplication:LSApplicationProxy: __BUNDLE___ (Placeholder) withPhase:0
Dec  4 15:41:31 iPod-de-aabarar lsd[74] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Updating installPhase for parent <NSProgress: phase=Loading; state=Waiting; fractionCompleted=0.000000> to 0
Dec  4 15:41:34 iPod-de-aabarar ubd[1404] <Error>: Couldn't create symlink at /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/DiagnosticLogs/Ubiquity/ubiquity-mmcs.log (No such file or directory)
Dec  4 15:41:34 iPod-de-aabarar ubd[1404] <Error>: Couldn't open log file /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/DiagnosticLogs/Ubiquity/ubiquity-mmcs-2014-12-04-154134+0100.log (No such file or directory)
Dec  4 15:41:34 iPod-de-aabarar ubd[1404] <Error>: Couldn't create symlink at /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/DiagnosticLogs/Ubiquity/ubiquity-mmcs.log (No such file or directory)
Dec  4 15:41:34 iPod-de-aabarar ubd[1404] <Error>: Couldn't open log file /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/DiagnosticLogs/Ubiquity/ubiquity-mmcs-2014-12-04-154134+0100.log (No such file or directory)
Dec  4 15:41:34 iPod-de-aabarar ubd[1404] <Error>: Couldn't create symlink at /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/DiagnosticLogs/Ubiquity/ubiquity-mmcs.log (No such file or directory)
Dec  4 15:41:34 iPod-de-aabarar ubd[1404] <Error>: Couldn't open log file /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/DiagnosticLogs/Ubiquity/ubiquity-mmcs-2014-12-04-154134+0100.log (No such file or directory)
Dec  4 15:41:34 iPod-de-aabarar ubd[1404] <Error>: Couldn't create symlink at /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/DiagnosticLogs/Ubiquity/ubiquity-mmcs.log (No such file or directory)
Dec  4 15:41:34 iPod-de-aabarar ubd[1404] <Error>: Couldn't open log file /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/DiagnosticLogs/Ubiquity/ubiquity-mmcs-2014-12-04-154134+0100.log (No such file or directory)
Dec  4 15:41:34 iPod-de-aabarar ubd[1404] <Error>: Couldn't create symlink at /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/DiagnosticLogs/Ubiquity/ubiquity-mmcs.log (No such file or directory)
Dec  4 15:41:34 iPod-de-aabarar ubd[1404] <Error>: Couldn't open log file /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/DiagnosticLogs/Ubiquity/ubiquity-mmcs-2014-12-04-154134+0100.log (No such file or directory)
Dec  4 15:41:34 iPod-de-aabarar ubd[1404] <Error>: Couldn't create symlink at /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/DiagnosticLogs/Ubiquity/ubiquity-mmcs.log (No such file or directory)
Dec  4 15:41:34 iPod-de-aabarar ubd[1404] <Error>: Couldn't open log file /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/DiagnosticLogs/Ubiquity/ubiquity-mmcs-2014-12-04-154134+0100.log (No such file or directory)
Dec  4 15:41:35 iPod-de-aabarar ubd[1404] <Error>: Couldn't create symlink at /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/DiagnosticLogs/Ubiquity/ubiquity-digest.log (No such file or directory)
Dec  4 15:41:35 iPod-de-aabarar ubd[1404] <Error>: Couldn't open log file /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/DiagnosticLogs/Ubiquity/ubiquity-digest-2014-12-04-154135+0100.log (No such file or directory)
Dec  4 15:41:37 iPod-de-aabarar SpringBoard[33] <Warning>: Killing __BUNDLE___ for app installation
Dec  4 15:41:37 iPod-de-aabarar itunesstored[91] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installing app for existing placeholder LSApplicationProxy: __BUNDLE___ (Placeholder)
Dec  4 15:41:37 iPod-de-aabarar itunesstored[91] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Creating installProgressForApplication:LSApplicationProxy: __BUNDLE___ (Placeholder) withPhase:1
Dec  4 15:41:37 iPod-de-aabarar lsd[74] <Warning>: LaunchServices: Updating installPhase for parent <NSProgress: phase=Loading; state=Waiting; fractionCompleted=0.600000> to 1
Dec  4 15:41:37 iPod-de-aabarar installd[60] <Notice>: 0x283000 handle_install_for_ls: Install of "/var/mobile/Media/Downloads/-9133206698769979491/-629968169170028521" requested by itunesstored
Dec  4 15:41:44 iPod-de-aabarar installd[60] <Error>: 0x283000 stage_package: Could not peruse package at /var/tmp/install_staging.Y5p5vc/foo_extracted
Dec  4 15:41:44 iPod-de-aabarar installd[60] <Error>: 0x283000 MobileInstallationInstall_Server: Could not stage the package
Dec  4 15:41:44 iPod-de-aabarar itunesstored[91] <Error>: 0x3c1000 MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices: failed with -1
Dec  4 15:41:44 iPod-de-aabarar itunesstored[91] <Warning>: ERROR: MobileInstallationInstallForLaunchServices returned nil
Dec  4 15:41:44 iPod-de-aabarar lsd[74] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installation failed for app __BUNDLE___
Dec  4 15:41:44 iPod-de-aabarar itunesstored[91] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installPhaseFinishedForProgress: __BUNDLE___.Installing - <NSProgress: phase=Installing; state=Failed; fractionCompleted=0.000000> called, removing progress from cache
Dec  4 15:41:44 iPod-de-aabarar lsd[74] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installation failed for app __BUNDLE___
Dec  4 15:41:44 iPod-de-aabarar itunesstored[91] <Warning>: LaunchServices: installPhaseFinishedForProgress: __BUNDLE___.Loading - <NSProgress: phase=Loading; state=Failed; fractionCompleted=1.000000> called, removing progress from cache
Dec  4 15:41:44 iPod-de-aabarar installd[60] <Error>: 0x283000 handle_install_for_ls: API failed
```

Any helps/ideas must be very appreciated!

Comment: Connect your device to your Mac and open the Xcode device console and post the results here.  It should show the installation error (provisioning, entitlements, etc).

Comment: I've updated with the log in Device Console

Comment: I started new project in XCode 6.1.1 .I am also getting same Prbolem, i could not able to create plist file also.How you create plist file ?

Comment: I've taken from another projet. It's the same template for all iOS version.